# How restrictive should be the use of "start-up"?

Tags: meaning

What newly created companies are "start-ups"?

According to the dictionary definition it is "A business or undertaking that has recently begun operation."

But, shouldn't we restrict the use to companies which are technical, or highly innovative?

Or could we call any new company (even a mom-and-pap shop, coffee place) a start-up too?

Comment: The [dedicated Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Startup_company) (which I believe makes this both genref and POB) includes: 'The exact definition of "startup" is widely debated[;] however at their core most definitions are similar to what the U.S. Small Business Administration describes as a "business that is typically technology oriented and has high growth potential".'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term refers to any company at its early stage of development, but the term became popular and is often associated with  hi-tech or other high-growth companies:

***[A startup](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/startup.asp)***:

> - ***is a company that is in the first stage of its operations*** These companies are often initially bank rolled by their entrepreneurial founders as they attempt to capitalize on developing a product or service for which they believe there is a demand. Due to limited revenue or high costs, most of these small scale operations are not sustainable in the long term without additional funding from venture capitalists.

Breaking down 'Startup':

> - ***In the late 1990s, the most common type of startup company was a dotcom.*** Venture capital was extremely easy to obtain during that time due to a frenzy among investors to speculate on the emergence of these new types of businesses. Unfortunately, most of these internet startups eventually went bust due to major oversights in their underlying business plans, such as a lack of sustainable revenue.
> - However, there were a handful of internet startups that did survive when the dotcom bubble burst. Internet bookseller Amazon.com and internet auction portal eBay are examples of such companies.

(Investopedia)

[***Start-up guides*** -  Retail business guides
***How to start a café or coffee shop***](http://startups.co.uk/how-to-start-a-cafe-or-coffee-shop/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why any new company couldn't be called a "start-up". It has just started up, after all. Otherwise the name would be counter-intuitive.

However, the word has now become such a cliché that it is perhaps best avoided. It was fun while it lasted. If what you're thinking of is a new company that makes software, or a company that provides computer or Internet services, then why not call it just that?

Comment: I agree. It is true that the word tends to lean towards idiotic app ideas.  But then what the hell do you call ordinary, well, startups such as ice cream shops?  And indeed as Cerberus says, just don't use the term - it's rubbish.